# How to access a nested variable in a referenced Hash.

Tags: ansible

I'm writing an Ansible Playbook and am trying to access a nested variable inside a referenced hash.

Here is my vars file:

```
SourceIPs:
  192.168.33.20:
    DestIP: 192.168.33.30
    Port: 22
  192.168.33.30:
    DestIP: 192.168.33.20
    Port: 22
```

Here is my task file:

```
- name: Testing varibale access.
  debug:
    msg: " Source IP: {{ ansible_host }} corresponding Port IP and Port {{ SourceIPs[' {{ansible_host}} '] }}  "
```

It fails when executing this saying dict_object has no variable called {{ ansible_host }}. So clearly its not converting that to the IP address of the current host.

However if I modify the task file to include a static host ip like so:

```
- name: Testing varibale access.
  debug:
    msg: " Source IP: {{ ansible_host }} corresponding Port IP and Port {{ SourceIPs['192.168.33.30'] }}  "
```

It works and get the values back for that particular host.

What I'm trying to achieve is get the values back associated to the host I'm currently executing on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Never do nesting in Jinja2 expressions. You can use variables inside them without any wrappings:

```
- name: Testing varibale access.
  debug:
    msg: " Source IP: {{ ansible_host }} corresponding Port IP and Port {{ SourceIPs[ansible_host] }} "
```